# How can I find out what keys were missing when a map was processed in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a map of items to process:

```
fun processAll(items: Map<Int, CustomObject>) {
        items.forEach {
            process(anotherSet[it.key])
        }
    }
```

What I want to do is for keys that were not processed i.e. the `anotherSet` has keys that were not part of the `items` I would like to
call another method to do something with those.
How can I do this in a Kotlin specific way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose `anotherSet` is actually a `Map`, given how you use it. Then you can get the residual map from it by subtracting all the keys that are contained in the `items` map:

```
val remaining = anotherSet - items.keys
for ((key, value) in remaining) {
   ...
}
```

You can play with the runnable example here: https://pl.kotl.in/DQVanLYrp

Comment: The `values` in the 2 maps are different. The keys are the same i.e. integers. Does that affect this approach?

Comment: No, here we're getting a map without other map's _keys_, so its _values_ do not matter.